# Form submits even if validation fails

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning Javascript, so bear with me if my question seems silly...

I need to create an html form and run some validation on the fields. Regardless of whether the fields are correctly filled or not, I get an error 404 when hitting the submit button. If I copy/paste someone else's code that does the same thing, it works fine. The file "somepage.php" does not exist, but neither does it for the other person's code.

I coded it in CodeLobster, then in Notepad++. No change.

Here's the HTML file, and further down is the content of the javascript file...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Registration Form</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="somepage.php" onsubmit="checkLogin()" method="post" >

                Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="nameF" /><br />
                Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="emailF" /><br />

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />    

        </form>
    </body>

</html>

function checkLogin()
{
   var emailPattern = /^\w+([\.\-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.\-]?\w+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i;
   var email = document.getElementById('emailF').value;
   var name = document.getElementById('name').value;    

    if (email == "")
    {
        alert("Please enter valid email address.");
       document.getElementById('emailF').select();
        document.getElementById('emailF').focus();
       return false;
    } else if   (name == "") {
        alert("Please enter your name.");
       document.getElementById('nameF').select();
        document.getElementById('nameF').focus();
       return false;
    }  else if (!emailPattern.test(email)) {
        alert("The email address entered is invalid");
       document.getElementById('emailF').select();
        document.getElementById('emailF').focus();
       return false;
    }
    return true;    
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to work if "somepage.php" does not exist?

Comment: there's absolutely no way this form will work if there's not a valid action. Once the function checkLogin returns true, it will fire up the action described in your form. If that page doesn't exist, it returns a 404 error. Perhaps someone else's code is returning false, and that page never gets fired.

Comment: The question title is misleading, that is not actually what OP is asking.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is not that the page is missing (you know that already). The problem is your form submits anyway, even if validation fails.

The `form.onsubmit` method should return `false` to prevent the form submitting. In other words, this:

```
<form action="somepage.php" onsubmit="checkLogin()" method="post" >
```

Should be:

```
<form action="somepage.php" onsubmit="return checkLogin()" method="post" >
```

Of course, if the form does validate, it will correctly proceed to `somepage.php` at which point you will expect to get a `404` error as the page doesn't exist.

Comment: Agreed. You need the return statement in the event handler.

Comment: I'm new to this site as well... Here's the rest of my reply:

First of all, thank-you for the quick reply.
Secondly, yes, I realize now that the question title should have been worded differently. Mia culpa.
It makes sense that if the function returns true, then "action" should take effect. I did play around with it and it didn't work as it should. But at this point, I don't remember why. I'm going to try it out again tonight and give a little more info.
Thanks!